Bayesian multivariate regression with repeated measures
I am trying to estimate variance components (specifically, genetic correlations) using mixed-effects models. My random effect is subject id and my dependent variables y1 and y2 are categorical scores obtained from two different tests. Each subject has been tested multiple times for each test, but the number of times differs between subjects (e.g. subject 1 might have undergone test 1 once and test 2 twice , while subject 2 might have undergone test 1 three times and test 2 two times), therefore each subject has a different number of repetitions of y1 and y2. y1 and y2 are kept in two separate datasets.
Is there a way to run a multivariate model while keeping all repetitions for both y1 and y2? How should I combine the two datasets to do so? Or should I just use a single value for y1 and y2 for each subject? I am using R packages MCMCglmm and brms.
I hope my question is clear enough.
